# Benchmarking controller action code to find slow points

Tags: c#, .net-core, benchmarking

I have a dotnet core web api application, and one of my controller actions is not as fast as I want it to be.

What is the best way to add timers around my code to see (at a high level) which parts of my controller action code are taking the longest.

The idea is to get an high level understanding of where I should focus the performance improvements are in my controller action code.

Comment: split the action into blocks. Make an estimate how long each block should take. If it takes longer than that then log the time it took. This should allow you to narrow the problem down

Comment: Perhaps look into using https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet. I have used it for other use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple helper class, which allows me to wrap code/functions like this:

```
using (new TimeProcess(duration => _logger.Trace($"{nameof(FunctionToMeasure)}) took: {duration.TotalMilliseconds:F0}ms")))
{
    /// Code to measure
 }
```